# How to scroll a RichTextBox control to a given point regardless of caret position

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

In my WinForms app I have a RichTextBox control containing a long text. I need to scroll it programmatically to a given point (expressed as a character index), regardless of where the selection caret is located. I need a method like this:

```
//scroll the control so that the 3512th character is visible.
rtf.ScrollToPosition(3512);
```

All answers to similar questions that I have found use the `ScrollToCaret()` method, which is fine if you want to scroll to the caret position. But I need to scroll to a different position rather than the caret, and without changing the caret position. How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try this `int s = rtb.SelectionStart;
rtb.SuspendLayout();
rtb.SelectionStart = 12334;
rtb.ScrollToCaret();
rtb.SelectionStart = s;
rtb.ResumeLayout();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change scrollbar position in TextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494162/change-scrollbar-position-in-textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SendMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) to send a [`WM_VSCROLL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-vscroll) message to the RichEdit control, specifying `SB_THUMBPOSITION` in the `LOWORD` of `wParam` and the absolute vertical position to scroll to in the `HIWORD`.

The [GetPositionFromCharIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getpositionfromcharindex) method (belongs to [TextBoxBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase), so it applies to the TextBox class, too) returns the relative *physical* position where a char in a specific position is displayed (the value can be negative if the char position is above the current scroll position and it's the difference between the current scroll position and the char position if it's below it - unless the current scroll position is `0`).

---

Assume your RichTextBox is named `richTextBox1`:

- Use, e.g., [Regex.Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match) to determine the position of a word or phrase; the position of the matched patterned is returned by the Index property of the Match.
- Check the current offset with `GetPositionFromCharIndex(0)`
- Add the absolute value of the offset defined by the current vertical position, to the value - expressed in pixels - returned by **`GetPositionFromCharIndex(matchPos)`**, where `matchPos` is the position of a char / word / pattern to scroll to.
- Call `SendMessage` using the calculated position and specifying to move the thumb to this position passing `SB_THUMBPOSITION` as part of wParam.

```
var matchPos = Regex.Match(richTextBox1.Text, @"some words").Index;

var pos0 = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(0).Y;
var pos = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(matchPos).Y + Math.Abs(pos0 - 1);

SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, pos << 16 | SB_THUMBPOSITION, 0);
```

Native methods declaration:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

private const uint WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
private const int SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same methodology implemented in the [TextBoxBase.ScrollToCaret Method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TextBoxBase.cs,0d71a197337768c8,references) to accomplish this.  This methodology is based on using the COM based [Text Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/text-object-model) implemented by the underlying RichEdit control.

The following defines the extension method `ScrollToCharPosition`. It uses abbreviated definitions of the [ITextDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tom/nn-tom-itextdocument) and [ITextRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tom/nn-tom-itextrange) interfaces.

```
public static class RTBExtensions
{

    public static void ScrollToCharPosition(this RichTextBox rtb, Int32 charPosition)
    {
        const Int32 WM_USER = 0x400;
        const Int32 EM_GETOLEINTERFACE = WM_USER + 60;
        const Int32 tomStart = 32;

        if (charPosition < 0 || charPosition > rtb.TextLength - 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(charPosition), $"{nameof(charPosition)} must be in the range of 0 to {rtb.TextLength - 1}.");
        }

        // retrieve the rtb's OLEINTERFACE and use the Interop Marshaller to cast it as an ITextDocument
        // The control calls the AddRef method for the object before returning, so the calling application must call the Release method when it is done with the object.
        ITextDocument doc = null;
        SendMessage(new HandleRef(rtb, rtb.Handle), EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, IntPtr.Zero, ref doc);
        ITextRange rng = null;
        if (doc != null)
        {
            try
            {
                rng = (RTBExtensions.ITextRange)doc.Range(charPosition, charPosition);
                rng.ScrollIntoView(tomStart);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (rng != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rng);
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
            }
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private extern static IntPtr SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, ref ITextDocument lParam);

    [ComImport, Guid("8CC497C0-A1DF-11CE-8098-00AA0047BE5D")]
    private interface ITextDocument
    {
        [MethodImpl((short)0, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void _VtblGap1_17();
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(15)]
        ITextRange Range([In] int cp1, [In] int cp2);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("8CC497C2-A1DF-11CE-8098-00AA0047BE5D")]
    private interface ITextRange
    {
        [MethodImpl((short)0, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
        void _VtblGap1_49();
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime), DispId(0x242)]
        void ScrollIntoView([In] int Value);
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**: `richtextbox1.ScrollToCharPosition(50)`

Comment: Thank you. I'll try first the approaches suggested in the comments, as they look simpler. I'll try your approach if they don't work.

Comment: @CesarGon, if you are attempting the proposed `WM_VSCROLL /GetPositionFromCharIndex`, be aware that those are limited to using 16 bit coordinate values.  Depending on font height, you will run into problems after a few thousands lines.  This may not be an issue for your usage, but you should be aware of the limitation.  Also realize that `GetPositionFromCharIndex` can return a negative values, so you need to accommodate for that as well.   Good luck.