# RichTextBox doesn't scroll properly when resized and shows an extra whitespace

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scrollbar, richtextbox

The RichTextBox control appears to have this strange bug that I'm trying to find a way around it.

Suppose you have a RichTextBox control with enough text to show the vertical scrollbar. Then, you increase the height of the RichTextBox while scrolled to the bottom (but not enough to hide the scrollbar). At that point, the RichTextBox will only show the amount of text that was previously visible on the smaller size and add an extra whitespace below the text. If you try to scroll down (or up) even a tiny bit, it immediately repaints itself correctly. This is how it looks like in both cases:

| After resize | After trying to scroll |
| --- | --- |
| [image: RichTextBox with extra whitespace at the bottom] | [image: RichTextBox without the extra whitespace] |

Here's a complete example to demonstrate the problem:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Location = new Point(12, 12);
        rtb.Size = new Size(150, 100);
        rtb.Lines = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(i => $"Line {i:00}").ToArray();
        rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.TextLength;
        rtb.ScrollToCaret();
        this.Controls.Add(rtb);

        var btn = new Button { Text = "Resize", AutoSize = true };
        btn.Location = new Point(rtb.Right + rtb.Margin.Right + btn.Margin.Left, 3);
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += (o, e) => rtb.Height = rtb.Height == 100 ? 200 : 100;
    }
}
```

Here it is in action:

[image: Demo]

As a workaround, I tried calling `rtb.ScrollToCaret();` in the `SizeChanged` event handler, which seemed to fix the problem but ended up causing some other weird glitches randomly. I tried to see if `rtb.Refresh();`, `rtb.Invalidate();`, or `rtb.PerformLayout();` would be of any help but none of that worked.

Is there any other way to get around this problem?

Note: the TextBox control (with `Multiline = true` and `Scrollbars = Vertical`) does *not* suffer from the same problem; only RichTextBox.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2, but I managed to reproduce in .NET 7.0 as well.

Comment: Have you thought about calling `ScrollToCaret()` again, right after you have set the new Height (which is relative to the WinForms's Control height, not the virtual View of the Win32 Control)? You could also send `EM_SETSCROLLPOS`, but it may be tricky to calculate

Comment: A few notes here: [Synchronize the Scroll position of two Controls with different content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67907473/7444103) (C# code at the bottom, in case you're interested)

Comment: @Jimi Okay, thank you. I will check the linked answer and see if it helps. I'm not sure I understand this part though: _"right after you have set the new Height (which is relative to the WinForms's Control height"_ Is that not the same as calling it in `SizeChanged` as mentioned above or are you referring to a different point in time and/or different trigger?

Comment: I don't see your code subscribing to that event here, anyway it could be the same thing, but I don't see why you'd need a second event handler just to call `rtb.ScrollToCaret();` when you can do that right after `rtb.Height = rtb.Height == 100 ? 200 : 100;` and also avoid scrolling the Control just because it's size changed, which may happen for other reasons (though it might be the desired effect) -- As a note, always specify the .NET version you're targeting, it may heavily affect the behavior of some Controls (the RTB is among these)

Comment: @Jimi That was just a minimal example to demonstrate the problem. In the real-life scenario, the RTB is docked on a UserControl that's docked on a form that can be resized/maximized by the user. So, I have no control over _when_ the RTB will be resized. I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2 but .NET 7.0 seems to have the same problem. I added this information to the question.

Comment: I actually don't _want_ to scroll the RTB when its size changes. That's not what I'm trying to do. Calling `ScrollToCaret` in `OnSizeChanged` was just a workaround to try and avoid the issue described above. But as I said in the question, although it did appear to solve the problem, it caused other unpredictable and difficult-to-reproduce glitches (e.g., sometimes, the scrollbar will "fight" you while you're trying to scroll, etc.). That's why I had to revert the "fix" and am looking for a better one.

Comment: Not sure what problems you're referring to. `ScrollToCaret()` uses the Text Object Model's Document object to scroll the Control to the current caret position and update the scrollbars. This may of course cause a slight flickering, if the method is called repeatedly while the Control is being resized (suppose the method is called when `SizeChanged` is raised). Other than that, it ought to behave in a pretty *predictable* manner -- In this department, .NET 4.7.2+ and .NET 5+ handle the method the same (the Win32 Control is the same)

Comment: `sometimes, the scrollbar will "fight" you while you're trying to scroll`  You can't really resize the RichTextBox and Scroll at the same time, so you're doing something different.  Just putting `rtb.ScrollToCaret();` in the button event does seem to solve it.