# How to detect richtextbox's "scroll up" event

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Im using a timer to append text into richtextbox and automatically scroll to bottom:

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Tick += AutoAppendText;
    timer.Interval = 500;
    timer.Start();
}

private void AutoAppendText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox.AppendText($"{DateTime.Now:hh:mm:ss.fff} : Hello");
    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

I was hoping is there any way when I'm scrolling up
I can turn off the auto scrollToCaret.

Comment: [GetScrollInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollinfo) -- If you want to see an implementation, check, e.g., [Synchronize the Scroll position of two Controls with different content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67907473/7444103) (C# code at the bottom)

Comment: That control has a `VScroll` event and a `MouseWheel` event. Handle them, and set a flag that you check in your `AutoAppendText` handler

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ScrollAwareRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public event EventHandler ScrollUp;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
        const int SB_THUMBTRACK = 5;
        const int SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4;

        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
        {
            int scrollEventType = m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF;
            if (scrollEventType == SB_THUMBTRACK || scrollEventType == SB_THUMBPOSITION)
            {
                OnScrollUp();
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnScrollUp()
    {
        ScrollUp?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would `SB_THUMBTRACK` or `SB_THUMBPOSITION` alone indicate a *scroll up*? There are other parameters that you can check to identifiy the direction of the scroll, when handling `WM_VSCOLL`. `GetScrollInfo()` is often used instead (as describe above) because of the limitation of having 16bit values only (and a couple of other details)