# MouseWheel event in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, mousewheel

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(richTextBox1.Focused)
    {
        
    }
}
```

I am using **Windows forms RichTextbox**, and my question is how do I make controls for **scrolling up** **and down** with my **mouse wheel**?
And also how would I get rid of mouse clicking, so that **|** line when clicked on text.

Comment: What does it mean, in practice, *make controls for scrolling up and down*? Do you mean you have a (read-only?) RichTextBox without Scrollbars? -- The *line* is called Caret. There's a Win32 function to hide the Caret, it's [HideCaret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-hidecaret). To keep it simple, you can call it in `SelectionChanged`

Comment: If you want to scroll a RichTextBox / TextBox in code, see [Synchronize the Scroll position of two Controls with different content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67907473/7444103) (C# code at the bottom)

Comment: I wanted to scroll down and up with my mouse wheel. So when focused, I can go up and down with mousewheel.

Comment: HideCaret didn't work in my case. I put it inside of `richTextBox1.SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {HideCaret(); }` and this was the function: `public void HideCaret() { HideCaret(this.Handle); }`.

Comment: `this.Handle` means the Handle of the Form. You want to pass in `richTextBox1.Handle` (or `(sender as Control).Handle`)

Comment: That works, thanks. What about mouse moving up and down. Below code is throwing null exception, probably copy pasted from ChatGPT, and link that you given it's about using scroll on the right side I think. I want to use mouse wheel.

Comment: I've asked a few questions, in my first comment. You haven't said what the problem is with the mouse wheel, yet, or described how the RichTextBox is configured. Add these details to the question (not in comments), along with any other information that can clarify your context. Otherwise, I don't know what to tell you

Comment: I am sorry to cause missunderstanding. So **richtextbox1** would get output log of folders that were transfered. I don't have read-only but I cannot scroll up or down with my mouse wheel.