# Sync 2 TextBox scroll bars on mousewheel from either?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, scrollbar, mousewheel

I've inherited a VB.net WinForm. There's 2 equal length arrays that are generally 600+ long that output to 2 fixed location/size WinForm TextBoxes called `RanTextBox` and `PosTextBox`. I need the 2 TextBoxes to scroll in unison/sync as there are no line/labels so matching lines from one box to the other gets confusing pretty much immediately after you mouse wheel in either. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: [Synchronize the Scroll position of two Controls with different content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67898346/7444103)

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title. That's what tags are for.

Comment: So I cannot do this as-is? I have to convert to RichTextBox? I appreciate the link but maybe some context please!

Comment: You didn't thoroughly read what's in that post. See the first ▶ point