# How can I change the scroll position of a richtextbox?

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

```
private void richTextBox1_VScroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox2.?= richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(0);
}
```

What should I put instead of "?" to set the scroll position of richTextBox1 on Y?
Or how else can I implement synchronous scrolling?

Comment: See the following post: [C#: Synchronize Scroll Position of two RichTextBoxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1827323/6630084)

Comment: [How to scroll a RichTextBox control to a given point regardless of caret position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65222953/7444103)