# Use button to scroll down Richtextbox 4 lines

Tags: vb.net, button, richtextbox, textchanged

I have a RichTextBox in vb.net which shows data from a .txt file using the "ReadAllText" methode.

As this program is running on a device with a touchscreen, i want to use "big", real buttons to scroll up and down rather than a scrollbar.

So i made a "scroll up" and "scroll down" button. The scroll down button is supposed to scroll down 4 lines from the last visible one. So if the Textbox looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

i am seeing

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

due to the size of the textbox and i click the "scroll down" button, it should now scroll down 3 lines. So i should be seeing

```
5
6
7
8
9
```

however i can't seem to make it work like this.

This is what my code looks like currently:

```
        Dim lastVisibleLine As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(RichTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(New Point(0, RichTextBox1.Height)))

        Dim scrollToLine As Integer = lastVisibleLine + 4


        Dim charIndex As Integer = RichTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(scrollToLine)
        If charIndex >= 0 Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = charIndex
            RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
        End If
```

however if i currently see lines 1-5 in the textbox, this makes it jump straight to 10-15.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: textboxes have no lines, so you must set SelectionStart at the next position

Comment: Are you expecting the users to be editing the data in the richtextbox?  Maybe a list box type control might make things easier for you.

Comment: OT, the WinForms `RichTextBox` has its own `LoadFile` method so you probably ought to use that to load the data. It also has a `SaveFile` method.

Comment: A scrollbar doesn't move the caret but your code does. is that what you want or did you just feel that you had to do it that way?

Comment: [How to scroll a RichTextBox control to a given point regardless of caret position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65222953/7444103)