# How to get the position of the default vertical scroll bar in winforms textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, textbox

I need to get the position of the default vertical scrollbar in a winforms textbox.
So far i only managed to find a way to get the position of a custom scrollbar, but not of the default one created from VS designer

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494162/change-scrollbar-position-in-textbox/4494331) should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]

static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).